# Error when setting up google analytics in swift 2 and xcode 7 beta 4

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, swift2

I set up my xcode project wit cocoapods, added google analytics as pod. Afterwards I imported the GoogleService-info.plist directly below my project file. Bridge header is also created, and code added in the AppdDelegate. During compilation, everything runs fine, but when I start the debugger, I receive those errors:

```
2015-08-14 16:45:25.866 GetOut[30738:3729265] Client ID must not be nil or empty.
2015-08-14 16:45:25.867 GetOut[30738:3729265] Client ID must not be nil or empty.
2015-08-14 16:45:25.867 GetOut[30738:3729265] GCM Sender ID must not be nil or empty.
2015-08-14 16:45:25.867 GetOut[30738:3729265] Attempted to configure [Identity, Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, CloudMessaging].
2015-08-14 16:45:25.867 GetOut[30738:3729265] Successfully configured [Analytics, AdMob].
2015-08-14 16:45:25.867 GetOut[30738:3729265] Failed to configure [SignIn, AppInvite, CloudMessaging].
2015-08-14 16:45:25.867 GetOut[30738:3729265] Subspecs not present, so not configured [Identity]. 
assertion failed: Error configuring Google services: Optional(Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-200 "Unable to configure GGL." UserInfo=0x170661400 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Check formatting and location of GoogleService-Info.plist., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to configure GGL., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to parse supplied GoogleService-Info.plist. See log for details.}): file /Users/xxx/Documents/Eigene Dateien/Appdesign/GetOut/GetOut/GetOut/AppDelegate.swift, line 30
```

The debugger stopps with this screen:

```
0x1006bdeec <+144>: bl     0x1006fc228               ; function signature     specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Exploded> of Swift.(_assertionFailed (Swift.StaticString, Swift.String, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1)
0x1006bdef0 <+148>: mov    x0, x24
0x1006bdef4 <+152>: bl     0x100749c50               ; swift_release
0x1006bdef8 <+156>: mov    x0, x19
0x1006bdefc <+160>: bl     0x100756cc8               ; swift_unknownRelease
```

It seems for me that the .plist cant be found during processing - but I can not figure out why? I checked the guide https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift carefully, but still can not figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue now. I changed my cocoapods file from /Google to /GoogleAnalytics - and it worked. –

Comment: Hi, I seem to have run into the same issue, but not able to follow your answer, which cocoapods file are you talking abt, can you please help me in this

Comment: As I only needed google analytics, and not the whole package with google ads and so on, I changed the cocoa pods ini file and used /GoogleAnalytics instead of /Google in there.