# Google Cloud Messaging. Error configuring Google services: Optional(Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-200 "Unable to configure GGL."

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

im trying to integrate GCM to my iOS App following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift).

When i run i get this assertion:

```
assertion failed: Error configuring Google services: Optional(Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-200 
"Unable to configure GGL." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Check formatting and location of GoogleService-Info.plist., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to configure GGL., 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to parse supplied GoogleService-Info.plist. See log for details.}): file /Users/alex/Desktop/Proyectos/____/_____/AppDelegate.swift, line 42
```

And i already added '*GoogleService-Info.plist*' into the root of my project and added it in all targets.

So i end up googling for this error, where i can find different solutions:

1. [Changing the pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013023/error-when-setting-up-google-analytics-in-swift-2-and-xcode-7-beta-4)
2. [Adding them as shared resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294380/unable-to-find-googleservice-info-plist-while-trying-to-integrate-google-sign)

But neither didn't work for me.
Notice i checked the file is on 'Copy Bundle Resources',all targets and in the root directory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to make sure your `GoogleService-Info.plist` is copied to a correct location, see [this image](http://i.imgur.com/WvNjVsQ.png)

Comment: Well this is not the root directory, but I'm pretty sure that i also draged the file to the project directory wich is the defAult and i was getting the same

Comment: You should provide a screenshot of your XCode project navigator, also the file path in your mac's finder. You are not suppose to drag the plist file to some random root directory.

Comment: @ztan i added those images, if you need more info just tell me, thx!

Comment: The file location seems file. When you dragged the plist to your project, did you check the `copy items if needed` option? Also you can try to generate a plist file again with your APNS certificate.

Comment: The file location seems file? what you mean? Yes, i tried  both ways (copy items un/checked)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89787/discussion-between-godfather-and-ztan).